# Mongodb group collection entries by day from timestamp, performance optimisation

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb

I have a Node web app that uses mongodb to store data. I have a Messages collection that looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut",
    "pubDate": "2014-01-16T14:15:33.792Z",
    "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
    "id": "a9baa2f0-7eb8-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
  },
  {
    "message": "labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
    "pubDate": "2014-01-16T14:01:24.198Z",
    "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
    "id": "af550860-7eb6-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
  },
  {
    "message": "laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in",
    "pubDate": "2014-01-17T01:12:27.277Z",
    "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
    "id": "6dff53d0-7f14-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
  },
  {
    "message": "voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat",
    "pubDate": "2014-01-17T01:10:17.249Z",
    "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
    "id": "207ea110-7f14-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
  }
...
]
```

I'd like to run a query that groups by day based on the pubDate timestamp, resulting in output:

```
[
  {
    "items":[
      {
        "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut",
        "pubDate":"2014-01-16T14:15:33.792Z",
        "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
        "id":"a9baa2f0-7eb8-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
      },
      {
        "message":"labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
        "pubDate":"2014-01-16T14:01:24.198Z",
        "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
        "id":"af550860-7eb6-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
      }
    ],
    "day":"2014-01-16T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "items":[
      {
        "message":"laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in",
        "pubDate":"2014-01-17T01:12:27.277Z",
        "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
        "id":"6dff53d0-7f14-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
      },
      {
        "message":"voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat",
        "pubDate":"2014-01-17T01:10:17.249Z",
        "pubTimezone": "America/Tijuana"
        "id":"207ea110-7f14-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
      }
    ],
    "day":"2014-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
...
]
```

Ordered reverse day date order, the timezone has to be used to calculate the day date.
Results paged 50 per page.
Note that some days there are no items created, and the pubDates are all ISODate format in the db.

I've read through a few posts about grouping however they all seem to do summation/count tasks rather than having all results grouped by day, in the output format I'm looking for. I've also read some blog [posts](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/03/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework.html) on aggregation frameworks and map reduce but not making much progress.

It would be great if it was possible to get total_messages and total_days as part of the same query, though I can always do that in code when I get the results.

The way I have my web app working, it pulls all messages in date desc order then in code sorts them by day, and the performance is pretty terrible, so I'm hoping to find a way to do the number crunching as the data is coming out of the db.

Any guidance and/or help greatly appreciated.

Comment: summation is about adding two integers together. counting is about incrementing a counter for each item found. What you want to do is stack items together : Different action, same principle. Have a look at $push aggregation operator. As an aside, I'm not sure you can handle the timezone field the way you want it to in an aggregation pipeline, you may have to use map/reduce instead to build more complex (although slower) grouping logic.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are in ISODate format, you should save them as this type in the database. The following line shows that the type is a string:

```
    "pubDate": "2014-01-16T14:15:33.792Z",
```

It should look like that:

```
{
  "message" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut",
  "pubDate" : ISODate("2014-01-16T14:15:33.792Z"),
  "pubTimezone" : "America/Tijuana",
  "id" : "a9baa2f0-7eb8-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
}
```

In the first proposal, let's assume you can change your strings to the ISODate type.
Then, you can use the aggregation framework functions to extract info about the date. MongoDB will return the values for year, month and day corresponding to the GMT-0 values. I think this is what you want, but if not, see the second solution.

Then, running the aggregation query should give you pretty much what you want:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{"$project":{year:{"$year":"$pubDate"},month:{"$month":"$pubDate"},day:{"$dayOfMonth":"$pubDate"},"item":{"message":"$message","pubDate":"$pubDate","pubTimezone":"$pubTimezone","id":"$id"}}},{"$group":{"_id":{"year":"$year","month":"$month","day":"$day"},"items":{"$push":"$item"},"count":{"$sum":1}}}]).result

[
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 17
    },
    "items" : [
        {
            "message" : "laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in",
            "pubDate" : ISODate("2014-01-17T01:12:27.277Z"),
            "pubTimezone" : "America/Tijuana",
            "id" : "6dff53d0-7f14-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
        },
        {
            "message" : "voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat",
            "pubDate" : ISODate("2014-01-17T01:10:17.249Z"),
            "pubTimezone" : "America/Tijuana",
            "id" : "207ea110-7f14-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 16
    },
    "items" : [
        {
            "message" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut",
            "pubDate" : ISODate("2014-01-16T14:15:33.792Z"),
            "pubTimezone" : "America/Tijuana",
            "id" : "a9baa2f0-7eb8-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
        },
        {
            "message" : "labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
            "pubDate" : ISODate("2014-01-16T14:01:24.198Z"),
            "pubTimezone" : "America/Tijuana",
            "id" : "af550860-7eb6-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 2
}
]
```

Note that you can only group on one list of fields. That means, you can get the counts of documents per day, use the number of documents returned by the aggregation as your number of days, but you will need to compute the total number of messages in your application, iterating through the documents.

Second solution for the cases where you can't have an ISODate type or you want to bucket your data on non-GMT times.
In that solution, compute an additional field, which represents the day to aggregate on. For example, you would create your documents with an additional 'date' field:

```
{
  "message" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut",
  "pubDate" :"2014-01-16T14:15:33.792Z",
  "pubTimezone" : "America/Tijuana",
  "date" : "2014-01-16"),
  "id" : "a9baa2f0-7eb8-11e3-b732-0b0c79e81098"
}
```

Then write a similar aggregation query, but using 'date' as your '_id' in the $group clause.
The advantage with a pre-computed field to aggregate on is that it will be faster, but it will also let you do a simple

```
find({"date":"2014-01-16"})
```

query to retrieve a subset of documents if you need to.
An advantage of using a simple find() command versus the aggregation framework is the latter needs to complete processing everything before returning results. The find() command will start returning results in batch, so it is quicker if you intend to page the results to your users.